# Using Proxy Ip Address in an HTTP GET request via advanced rest client chrome

Tags: proxy, http-headers, advanced-rest-client

I am trying to use a proxy ip address with advanced rest client chrome. But not able to figure out how to do so.

For sure there is no built in option for that, but perhaps I might pass some headers to use a free proxy.